# SQL Server check constraint on part of composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to learn SQL. Can't seem to find an answer to this or if I did I don't know enough SQL to recognize it as such. Can you create a table with a composite primary key and a check constraint on one of the key columns?

To be specific this fails with:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CH_AddressType". The conflict occurred in database "tempdb", table "dbo.#t

If I comment out the check constraint in the table create and uncomment the alter table the insert works.

Do the two ways of creating the table... create the same table? What am I missing?

```
create table #t 
(
    entityNo        int             not null,
    addressType     char(1)         not null,
    valid           char(1)         not null,

    address1        varchar(256)    not null,
    address2        varchar(256)    not null,
    city            varchar(128)    not null,
    stateCode       char(2)         not null,
    zipCode         char(5)         not null,

    dtCreate        datetime        not null,
    dtUpdate        datetime        not null

    constraint PK_Address_Entity 
         primary key (entityNo, addressType),

    constraint CH_AddressValid 
         check (valid in ('Y', 'N')),
    constraint CH_AddressType 
         check (valid in ('H', 'V'))
)
go

--alter table #t
--  add constraint CH_Address_Type check ((addressType) in ('H', 'V'))
--go

insert into #t (entityNo, addressType, valid, address1, address2, city, stateCode, zipCode, dtCreate, dtUpdate)
values (100, 'H', 'Y', '100 Some Street', '' , 'Someville', 'PA', '19335', '2016-10-08', '2016-10-08')

select * from #t
go

drop table #t
go
```

Comment: Valid in ? where you find that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`constraint CH_AddressType check (valid in ('H', 'V'))`

should be

`constraint CH_AddressType check (addressType in ('H', 'V'))`

Comment: yes. Is there a way to close the question / mark it as accepted (it's probably right under my nose as well).

Comment: @Joe click the grey `✓` on the answer's left , right under the vote part